# Alamofire post data not sending expressjs

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, express, alamofire

I'm trying to send JSON data from IOS Application using Alamofire to a express server. But I'm not able to retrieve the data in the express application when I check the data being logged out it displays a empty object. I can't figure out why I'm not retrieving the data in the express application.

Below is an example of the format of the data being sent

```
["data": [{
      "dfsget4gsfs" : {
        "step_count" : 38,
        "effective_time_frame" : {
          "time_interval" : {
            "start_date_time" : "2018-01-01T17:07:02.425Z",
            "end_date_time" : "2018-01-01T17:08:03.862Z"
          }
        }
      }
    }, {
      "dfsget4gsfs" : {
        "step_count" : 15,
        "effective_time_frame" : {
          "time_interval" : {
            "start_date_time" : "2018-01-01T16:55:09.324Z",
            "end_date_time" : "2018-01-01T17:02:08.031Z"
          }
        }
      }
    }]]
```

The Alamofire snippet in the IOS application

```
Alamofire.request("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:3005/demoendpoint", method: .post, parameters:  ["data": dataObject], encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody)
```

The endpoint in the express application

```
routes.post("/demoendpoint", async function(req, res) {
    console.log("demo endpoint");
    console.log(req);
});
// body: {} The body which is logged from the req above
```

Versions 

node: 8.0.0

express: 4.16.2

Alamofire: 4.4

Comment: hey @Brent, are you using a bodyParser.urlencoded ?

Comment: @tariklefi I do, Ive got it working but moving some bodyParser above my endpoint files which I was importing in. I guess this prevent the endpoints from using bodyParser config. Thanks for the input.